# Angular ng-repeat like parameters binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to bind angular ng-repeat parameters to do something like this:

```
ng-repeat="[BIND_THIS]"
```

Furthermore, I'd like to be able to bind in this kind of scenario:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" placeholder="Custom template" typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" class="form-control">
```

Would become

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" placeholder="Custom template" typeahead="[BIND_THIS]" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" class="form-control">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you request is not possible without a workaround. From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> The expression indicating how to enumerate a collection. These formats
>   are currently supported:
>
> `variable in expression` – where variable is the user defined loop
>   variable and expression is a scope expression giving the collection to
>   enumerate.
>
> For example: `album in artist.albums`.
>
> (key, value) in expression – where key and value can be any user
>   defined identifiers, and expression is the scope expression giving the
>   collection to enumerate.
>
> For example: `(name, age) in {'adam':10, 'amalie':12}`.
>
> `variable in expression track by tracking_expression` – You can also
>   provide an optional tracking expression which can be used to associate
>   the objects in the collection with the DOM elements. If no tracking
>   expression is specified, ng-repeat associates elements by identity. It
>   is an error to have more than one tracking expression value resolve to
>   the same key. (This would mean that two distinct objects are mapped to
>   the same DOM element, which is not possible.)
>
> Note that the tracking expression must come last, after any filters,
>   and the alias expression.
>
> For example: `item in items` is equivalent to `item in items track by $id(item)`. This implies that the DOM elements will be associated by
>   item identity in the array.
>
> For example: `item in items track by $id(item)`. A built in `$id()`
>   function can be used to assign a unique `$$hashKey` property to each
>   item in the array. This property is then used as a key to associated
>   DOM elements with the corresponding item in the array by identity.
>   Moving the same object in array would move the DOM element in the same
>   way in the DOM.
>
> For example: `item in items track by item.id` is a typical pattern when
>   the items come from the database. In this case the object identity
>   does not matter. Two objects are considered equivalent as long as
>   their `id` property is same.
>
> For example: `item in items | filter:searchText track by item.id` is a
>   pattern that might be used to apply a filter to items in conjunction
>   with a tracking expression.
>
> `variable in expression as alias_expression` – You can also provide an
>   optional alias expression which will then store the intermediate
>   results of the repeater after the filters have been applied. Typically
>   this is used to render a special message when a filter is active on
>   the repeater, but the filtered result set is empty.
>
> For example: `item in items | filter:x as results` will store the
>   fragment of the repeated items as `results`, but only after the items
>   have been processed through the filter.
>
> Please note that `as [variable name] is not an operator but rather a
>   part of ngRepeat micro-syntax so it can be used only at the end (and
>   not as operator, inside an expression).
>
> For example: `item in items | filter : x | orderBy : order | limitTo : limit as results`.

What you could do is **[create a directive with template replacement](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)**.

Comment: You mean creating a directive that wraps the typeahead and $compile a concatenated string?

Comment: yep, just create a custom directive with template replacing

Comment: On it right now, I actually already had some kind of dynamic host for loading directives on the fly but I did not thought of that case. Clever!

Comment: All right, I did it with this solution and it works kind of well. Thanks!